# UIScrollView ContentOffset.y reset to 0 after performBatch

Tags: swift

I'm using https://github.com/OfTheWolf/TwitterProfile <- this library on my project.

It is the little bit application of XLStripPager.
Because I have to set the header View and pager.

The layout architecture is [image]

My Problem is this. When I set the expand the table cell label using `UITableView.automaticDimension`
expanding animation(?) is well worked. but after I scroll the table, the content offset.y is reset to zero. so even I tapped the bottom cell to expand, after that cell expanded when I move the scroll, the scrollView is set to the top(awkard...)

```
extension BottomViewController: LabelCellDelegate {
    func expand(cell: LabelCell) {
        let indexPath = cell.indexPath
        
        if !expandCheck[indexPath!.row] {
            expandCheck[indexPath!.row] = true
        }
        
        //offset = tableView.contentOffset.x
        
        tableView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
            cell.label.numberOfLines = 0
        }, completion: nil)
        
    }
}
```

I tried to print the scrollView Offset.
After click(expand) the cell the `offset.y` changed to `0`...

I don't know how to solve this problem.

I try to assign the right before the expand `contentOffset`.y at the `scrollViewDidScroll` but breaking error.

How to prevent the reset to zero offset ? Any other method ?

[image]